# Passing API data to view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can't figure out why my data is not being passed to View
I get the message Undefined variable: project

Can someone help identify where i am going wrong?

when i return $project->name straight from the controller it displays the response, however fails to pass to view.

Here is my controller function:

```
public function getApi(){

   $client = new Client();
     $response = $client->get('https://play.geokey.org.uk/api/projects/77');

        $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
         $project = json_decode($body);

    return view ('response', compact($project));


}
```

And here is my View:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Date of Creation</th>
        <th>Contribution Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>{{$project->name}}</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

`return view ('response', compact($project));`

Type

`return view ('response', compact('project'));`

Answer (score 1):

`return view ('response', compact('project'));` instead of `compact($project)`